# HtmlAgilityPack Youtube search in UWP c#

Tags: c#, web-scraping, youtube, uwp, html-agility-pack

in my UWP application i need to take the title and the link of the first video in a youtube page by HtmlAgilityPack, but the result is the following, and the value of title and href isn't show.

```
id="video-title" 
class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer" 
aria-label$="[[data.title.accessibility.accessibilityData.label]]" 
href$="[[computeHref_(data.navigationEndpoint)]]" 
title$="[[getSimpleString(data.title)]]" 
data="[[data.navigationEndpoint]]">
```

This is the code

```
var html = @"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cado+dalle+nubi+trailer+ita";

HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = web.Load(html);

var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div/div/div/div/h3/a");
string result = node.OuterHtml;
```

Comment: Did my answer works?

Answer (score 2):

Use `WebView` instead of `HtmlWeb` to get the HTML

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
webView.Navigate(new Uri(@"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cado+dalle+nubi+trailer+ita"));

private async void WebView_NavigationCompletedAsync(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    var siteHtML = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.innerHTML;" });
}
```

The first video was in the second index. So use `SelectNodes` and select the second index

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = web.Load(siteHtML );
string result = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/div/div/div/h3/a")[1].OuterHtml;
```

**Here is the final code**

```
WebView webView = new WebView();

public void GetFirstVideo(string UrlString)
{
    webView.Navigate(new Uri(UrlString));
    webView.NavigationCompleted -= WebView_NavigationCompletedAsync;  //To avoid multiple subscribe
    webView.NavigationCompleted += WebView_NavigationCompletedAsync;
}

private async void WebView_NavigationCompletedAsync(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    webView.NavigationCompleted -= WebView_NavigationCompletedAsync;  //To stop if there is any re-direct
    var siteHtML = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.innerHTML;" });
    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(siteHtML);
    var firstVideoTitle = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/div/div/div/h3/a")[1].OuterHtml;
}
```

Comment: Your solution take me this error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'